# Sort users by closer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geocoding

I have a rails 3 application with the geocoder gem. When a user create an account in my website, he gives me his address. With geocoder, I store his lat and his lng in my database so I could place him in a google map.

When a user make a search, he have to find the closest users to him.

For the moment, I calculate a radius with geocoder to find users in it :

```
bounds_calc = Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box(center, radius, units: :km)
users = User.where('? < addresses.lat AND addresses.lat < ?', bounds_calc[0], bounds_calc[2]).where('? < addresses.lng AND addresses.lng < ?', bounds_calc[1], bounds_calc[3])
```

What I want to do is to sort `users` from closest to farthest. Is there an easy way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe this gem can help you : https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails.

Comment: I think that if you use User.near, the results will automatically sorted by distance...

Comment: You calculate a *bounding box* and select users within that box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to sort my array of users with Geocoder :

```
results = results.sort_by { |x| Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([x.latitude, x.longitude], [loc.first, loc.second]) }
```

I've made my code before reading Peter Goldstein's answer so I don't know if his answer works. 
I prefere my solution because it can be called on any Array instead of the other which to be called on a geocoded instance.

However, I don't know which solution is the fastest.

Comment: I don't really understand your solution, as it doesn't appear to address the original question.  The solution written here (i) requires the list of users to be in memory first, which defeats the purpose of using PostGis and (ii) doesn't impose any kind of bounding box, which presumably is being imposed early when the results array is being built.  Using nearbys solves all of that in one request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got a geocoded user instance, you should be able to use the 'nearbys' method on the geocoded instance.  So for a user you should be able to write

```
user.nearbys(radius_in_miles)
```

where radius_in_miles is the radius of the bounding circle in miles.  The default ordering is nearest to farthest.